# React Navigation: Change all background color on switch bottom tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Is there a way to change the entire background color of the bottom tab when switching tabs in React Navigation 5?

Like this (tiktok app for example):

[Background black on first tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP3QG.jpg)


[Background white on first tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CDH7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `style` in `tabBarOptions`

```
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Feed"
  tabBarOptions={{
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    inactiveTintColor: '#fff',
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#000',
    }
  }}
>
  {/* screens */}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Use the currently active route information from the props to switch that color as needed.

Runnable example: https://snack.expo.io/@notbrent/createbottomtabnavigator---background-color

edit: it looks like I am actually mistaken about this and there isn't an obvious way to edit the tab bar background color based off of the active tab with standard bottom tab navigator. You can use `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator` to get this behavior easily, otherwise you will likely need to do some other wokaround, eg: implement a custom tab bar or extend the default tab bar.

Comment: yes, in edit, you describe exactly, if I not find an obvious way to make this, I will try the other ways you mentioned.